# Saving and retrving image from mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

In C#, I am trying to save and load an image. I am saving it into a mysql database (type longblob) and trying to load it back into an picture box. The problem i keep getting is  the error "Parameter is not valid", see code below

```
        ConnectionClass Sqlconnection = new ConnectionClass();
        Sqlconnection.ConnectionOpen();

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Insert into pictest(pic) values('"+ Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(richTextBox1.Rtf) + "')", Sqlconnection.connection);

        int num = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show(num + " Rows inserted ");

        Sqlconnection.ConnectionClose();

        OdbcDataReader rd = null;

        try
        {
            Sqlconnection.ConnectionOpen();

            string query = "select * from pictest where id = 1";

            cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, Sqlconnection.connection);

            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rd.Read())
            {
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])rd[1];

                ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes)); <--Parameter is not valid
                pictureBox1.Refresh();

                pictureBox1.Image = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);

            }

            Sqlconnection.ConnectionClose();
            rd.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception asd)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem " + asd.Message);

            Sqlconnection.ConnectionClose();

            if (rd != null)
            {
                rd.Close();
            }
        }
```

what exact is the problem? Is the image not saving correctly? it should be as it is saving to a longblob. The record for the image says System.Byte[]

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to inspect (via the debugger) the values inside `OdbcDataReader` before trying to cast the first field to `byte[]`.  Take a look at what type is actually stored in the `OdbcDataReader`

Using `SELECT *` is problematic performance wise.  It also leaves your `rd[1]` up for interpretation.  If the order of columns ever changes, your code could break.  Use `rd["your_column_name"]` to access the values.  As of right now I can't tell if index 1 is correct due to the `SELECT *` and non-named indexing into the `Items` array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why you need to store image in MySql?

Why not in physical drive? If its not a crucial data go for saving it in physical drive.

However, here is code to retrieve:

```
public byte [] getImage(int imageNumber)
{
        string strSql = "SELECT * FROM File";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Image");
        OdbcDataAdapter tempAP = new OdbcDataAdapter(strSql,this._objConn);
        OdbcCommandBuilder objCommand = new OdbcCommandBuilder(tempAP);
        tempAP.Fill(ds,"Table");

        try
        {
            this._objConn.Open();
            byte [] buffer = (byte [])ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[imageNumber]["Data"];
            return buffer;
        }
        catch{this._objConn.Close();return null;}
        finally{this._objConn.Close();}            
}
```

Courtesy:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6750/Storing-Images-in-MySQL-using-ASP-NET

For physical drive
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2113/C-Photo-Album-Viewer